# Unity - Why particle system gets transparent?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, particle-system, particles

I just created an particle system where you see a blinking add-icon. The problem is that if something gets behind the particle system, it gets transparent and I dont know why. I read that changing the shader could fix it, but it didnt work. I tried every shader in "Particles/..."

Here you how it looks like:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I seems that your object doesn't get transparent, but rather that it is being covered by the other object even though it should be in front of it.

Sorting is a common problem with objects that use some sort of blending:
In this case this is probably due to the other object being in a ui element. You could try to enforce the draw order by modifying the render queue in the material, or force it to use depth testing by using an alpha cutout shader instead (but its edges will not look as nicely anti-aliased without an extra MSAA or FXAA)